# Add static value to an enum in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, static-variables

I've created an enum that contains links like:

```
enum Links {
  Home = "/MyPage/Frontend/Home.html",
  AboutUs = "/MyPage/Frontend/AboutUs.html",
}
```

I want to make the first part of the link static.

I've tryed to create a static variable

```
public static baselink = "/MyPage/Frontend/";
```

and then call it in my enums.ts

In my enum.ts I want something like:

```
Home = baselink + "Home.html"
```

but I can't access to that variable and also I don't think it will work because I've a message that says:

> In an enum with string values calculated values are not allowed.

Comment: This doesn't currently seem possible, see [this ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16520) and [this ticket on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20440).

Answer (score 0):

A frozen object is functionally equal to an enum in TypeScript (do correct me if I'm wrong here). So, this should do:

```
const _BASELINK = "/MyPage/Frontend"

const Links = Object.freeze({
    Home: `${_BASELINK}/Home.html`,
    AboutUs: `${_BASELINK}/AboutUs.html`
})
```

Object.freeze() takes any object and makes it *readonly*. We wouldn't want anyone modifying the "enum".

`` is a handy syntax known as String Template that can be used to format Strings in run-time. It's not needed for this, but I like using it.